# Problema en árbol binario de busqueda c++

Tags: c++

tengo un problema al crear el método de insertar del árbol binario de búsqueda en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) me lanza el siguiente error:

```
argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "nodo *"
```

Y mi código de insertar es el siguiente:

```
void ingresar_elemento(ABB &arbol, Alumno dato) {
if (arbol == NULL) {
    numNodos++;
    arbol = new nodo;
    arbol->guardaObjeto(dato);
    arbol->guardaNodoIzq(NULL);
    arbol->guardaNodoDer(NULL);
}

else if (dato.dameNombre() < arbol->dameObjeto().dameNombre().c_str()) {
    arbol->guardaNodoIzq(ingresar_elemento(arbol->dameNodoIzq(), dato));
}

else if (dato.dameNombre() > arbol->dameObjeto().dameNombre().c_str()) {
    arbol->guardaNodoDer(ingresar_elemento(arbol->dameNodoIzq(), dato));
}

else if (dato.dameNombre() == arbol->dameObjeto().dameNombre().c_str()) {
    cout << "El elemento que ingreso ya existe" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
return arbol;
}
```

Comment: Una nota: ¿Cuál es el tipo devuelto por dameNombre? Deduzco por lo que veo que es `std::string`; si es así, el `c_str()` del final de cada `if` sobra.

Comment: PaperBird de echo al final se los quite no los necesite para nada. De igual forma gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas utilizando la instrucción `return` en un `void`, para solucionar esto cambias `void` por `nodo*`:

```
nodo* ingresar_elemento(ABB &arbol, Alumno dato) {
    if (arbol == NULL) {
        numNodos++;
        arbol = new nodo;
        arbol->guardaObjeto(dato);
        arbol->guardaNodoIzq(NULL);
        arbol->guardaNodoDer(NULL); 
    }

    else if (dato.dameNombre() < arbol->dameObjeto().dameNombre().c_str()) {
        arbol->guardaNodoIzq(ingresar_elemento(arbol->dameNodoIzq(), dato));
    }
    else if (dato.dameNombre() > arbol->dameObjeto().dameNombre().c_str()) {
        arbol->guardaNodoDer(ingresar_elemento(arbol->dameNodoIzq(), dato));
    }
    else if (dato.dameNombre() == arbol->dameObjeto().dameNombre().c_str()) {
        cout << "El elemento que ingreso ya existe" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    return arbol;
}
```